# How to specify precision of a float in a mapserver template?

Tags: wms, mapserver, getfeatureinfo

[This `GetFeatureInfo` query](http://arta.irrigation-management.eu/cgi-bin/mapserver?map=/var/cache/pthelma/mapserver-historical.map&info_format=text/html&LAYERS=Daily_evaporation_2015-04-06&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=20.7543,38.9926,21.1385,39.2669&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&QUERY_LAYERS=Daily_evaporation_2015-04-06&X=200&Y=130) will give you this result:

```
Evaporation = 1.0149659 mm
```

The template that produces the result is this:

```
<!-- mapserver template -->
[metadata_variable_name] = [value_0] [metadata_unit]<br>
```

How can I have it round the output to one decimal point? I.e. I want it to produce this instead:

```
Evaporation = 1.0 mm
```

Comment: Have you tried item formatting as in MapServer documentation 
`[item name="area" precision="2" commify="2" format="Area is $value"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
<!-- mapserver template -->
[metadata_variable_name] = [item name="value_0" precision="1"] [metadata_unit]<br>
```